# What is the best way to check the getopts status in bash?

Tags: bash, getopts

I am using following script :

```
#!/bin/bash
#script to print quality of man
#unnikrishnan 24/Nov/2010
shopt -s -o nounset
declare -rx SCRIPT=${0##*/}
declare -r OPTSTRING="hm:q:"
declare SWITCH
declare MAN
declare QUALITY
if [ $# -eq 0 ];then
printf "%s -h for more information\n" "$SCRIPT"
exit 192
fi
while getopts "$OPTSTRING" SWITCH;do
case "$SWITCH" in
h) printf "%s\n" "Usage $SCRIPT -h -m MAN-NAME -q MAN-QUALITY"
   exit 0
   ;;
m) MAN="$OPTARG"
   ;;
q) QUALITY="$OPTARG"
   ;;
\?) printf "%s\n" "Invalid option"
    printf "%s\n" "$SWITCH"
    exit 192
    ;;
*) printf "%s\n" "Invalid argument"
   exit 192
    ;;
esac
done
printf "%s is a %s boy\n" "$MAN" "$QUALITY"
exit 0
```

In this if I am giving the junk option :

```
./getopts.sh adsas
./getopts.sh: line 32: MAN: unbound variable
```

you can see it fails. it seems while is not working. What is the best way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely require MAN, then i suggest you don't make it an option parameter, but a positional parameter. Options are supposed to be optional.

However, if you want to do it as an option, then do:

```
# initialise MAN to the empty string
MAN=
# loop as rewritten by DigitalRoss
while getopts "$OPTSTRING" SWITCH "$@"; do
  case "$SWITCH" in
    m) MAN="$OPTARG" ;;
  esac
done
# check that you have a value for MAN
[[ -n "$MAN" ]] || { echo "You must supply a MAN's name with -m"; exit 1; }
```

Even better, print the usage message before exiting - pull it out into a function so you can share it with the -h option's case.

Answer (score 2):

The `getopts` builtin returns 1 ("false") when there are no option arguments.

So, your `while` never executes unless you have option arguments beginning with a `-`.

Note the last paragraph in the getopts section of bash(1):

```
          getopts  returns true if an option, specified or unspecified, is
          found.  It returns false if the end of options is encountered or
          an error occurs.
```

Answer (score 0):

The "best" solution is subjective. One solution would be to give default values to those variables that can be set by options.